# libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, fisheye

I have been working with Fish eye cameras which are connected to my tx2 processor using two usb 3.0 hubs,

When I used two cameras i didn't face any problem, but I have given 3 cameras to capture image, it states no space left on device.

I have tried the available trick to  run "rmmod uvcvideo" and then run "modprobe uvcvideo quirks=128" but that didn't do anything.

When I run Sudo ls /dev/video*

**/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2  /dev/video3**

Also my lsusb shows:
***Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub***

that means all are connected to usb hub but from the same port of my tx2.

I have also, altered the frame rate and tried but I didn't got any success.

Suggest me some possible solution